# React Native View onLayout re-renders every frame while children height animates

Tags: react-native, animation, layout, layout-animation, usecallback

To create a custom `View` with `translateY` I have to calculate the height of the container and content using `onLayout`. This worked perfectly, but today I've added an `Accordion` component which also animates. This happens to trigger the `onLayout` functions to render on every calculated frame, which makes my application very slow. I've tried adding the `useCallback` and the `LayoutAnimation` to fix this, but this both didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to trigger the `onLayout` only before and after the animation? I thought about adding a debounce to the `onLayout`, but hopefully, there is another solution.

```js
export default memo(({ translateY }) => {
  const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState(0);
  const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState(0);

  console.log('render', containerHeight, contentHeight);

  const onLayoutContainer = useCallback(event => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    const height = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    setContainerHeight(height);
  }, []);

  const onLayoutContent = useCallback(event => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    const height = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    setContentHeight(height);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View onLayout={onLayoutContainer}>
        <Animated.View
          onLayout={onLayoutContent}
          style={{ transform: [{ translateY }] }}
        >
            <Accordion />
            <Accordion />
            <Accordion />
            <Accordion />
            <Accordion />
            <Accordion />
        </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
});
```